# 'Since' with subjunctive past perfect

Tags: past-perfect, subjunctives, since

Suppose the following statement is true for one person.

> I have lived in the US since I was five, so I speak English naturally.

Another person wishes it were true for him, and says:

> If I had lived in the US **since** I was five, I would be speaking English naturally.

My doubt is about the use of ***since*** in the second sentence. I understand that (temporal) *since* is used to mark the beginning of a period that has continued up to the present and is normally used with the present perfect tense. This sentence is talking about the present, but it's not the present in the actual world but one in a world that didn’t come to be. Is it still correct to use *since* with the backshifted past perfect tense like this? If not, how should this idea be expressed?

Comment: Yes. That sentence sounds fine to me.

Comment: @EddieKal: Thanks.